# How does the magnetic field of an electron compare to the magnetic field produced by a bar magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

We are currently studying Moving charges and magnetism in school and we learned that moving charges produce magnetic field and that magnetic dipole moments also produce it.However, magnetic monopoles don't exist.If then, how does a moving point charge produce a magnetic field.It has to be a moving dipole???

Comment: An excellent question! I think it has been answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65335/ Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: Maaz, the electron is both (with the same "authorisation") - an electric charge AND a magnetic dipole. In a permanent magnet, the magnetic dipoles of the electrons are aligned in such a way that they produce a total magnetic field. [The magnetic field is as real as an electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/783366/magnetic-induction-as-a-reletivistic-effect-too)